# How do I restore a dead keyboard after activating filter keys when using remote desktop connection?

Tags: windows-7, terminal, remote-desktop

I was using a Windows Remote Desktop Connection to a Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal session on my Windows 7 PC and held the shift key down for more than eight seconds whilst I was thinking about what to type.  This activated Filter Keys on the Windows 7 PC.  I closed the Filter Keys panel without activating the feature and went back to the RDP session.  I then discovered that the keyboard no longer worked in the RDP session.  Disconnecting the session and reconnecting had no effect on the problem.

I have Googled and found no solution.

How do I re-enable the keyboard without having to reboot my logged in RDP session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your mouse,

1. go to the control panel
2. scroll to make the keyboard easier to use link
3. uncheck use filter keys
4. press ok

Comment: This works when performed on the Terminal Server session, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What i will suggest is to open the services panel from your workstation to the remote.
restart these services:

- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Remote Desktop Services